# How do I resize an image and surrounding container to fit in 100% of the screen—almost?

Tags: html, css, image

Okay. So final touch here (for now).

On the homepage at http://www.rfm-inc.com, how do I set the header/(slider) image and surrounding container to fill 100% of the screen at any screen size below the actual image size?

Here's what I've come up with so far, but it doesn't do what I want it to do:

```css
.flexslider .slides img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Above the actual image size, there should be margins to either side of the image.

Also, the answer has to consider that the height of the source image is 1350 and the height needs to change according to screen size as well without distorting the image. I.E., when the screen height is below 1350, the image remainder of the full height would be hidden or cropped.

I hope that makes sense. It's hard to explain stuff like this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Okay. Since I'm not a pro, sometimes that's hard for me. It seems like a lot to ask, but I've done my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For centering the image, which has `display: block` already set, you should use margin auto on left and right as:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

You should give `height: auto` to the image if you want it not be stretched or distorted. By default `height` is `auto` for most of the html elements including the `img` element. When the height of the viewport will go below 1350 css pixels, which usually is, a scrollbar would automatically be shown and the bottom portion of your image could only be screen after scrolling down. If you want to just crop away that portion so that on scrolling down no part of image would be shown then you should use your image as background-image to the container div with `background-size: cover`.